# How do I center my list?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center my list and for the life of me cannot figure it out no matter what I try. Obviously I am not trying the right things in the right places. Help and explain what it is I need to do. Thanks!

HTML

```
            <div id = "listwrapper">
                <h3>Partner Companies</h3>
                <ol id = "list">
                    <li><a href="http://store.steampowered.com/app/241240/">Steam Contraption maker</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.gamingonlinux.com/articles/contraption-maker-casual-game-will-come-to-linux.3026">Contraptions coming to Linux</a></li>
                    <li><a href="unity3d.com/">Unity game developer engine</a></li>
                </ol>
            </div>
```

And CSS

```
#listwrapper
{
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#list
{
    margin: auto;
}

#list li
{
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: `#listwrapper` needs to have a defined `width` property.

Comment: Are you trying to center the whole div, or just center the individual li tags or center the ul?

Comment: I put that code in a fiddle and everything is centered. What is the issue?

Comment: Im trying to center the whole list.

Comment: idk Its not showing up in my browser for some reason.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by centered? http://jsfiddle.net/fz63r3de/  looks centred to me

Comment: @Sai there is 40 px default padding added by user agent of the browser look on my answer to see an img showing that (you can not add img to comments that why i put it in the answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
margin: auto o; // should centre item
margin-left: auto; // for i.e
margin-right: auto; // for i.e
```

The above CSS should centre block level elements in all major browsers.

Venter the list as a whole rather than the li they should then remain in the correct order.

**Edit**
For reference the following css should enable the display of the numbers of ordering

```
li {
        float:left;
        margin:10px;
        list-style-position:inside;
    }
```

Comment: Have you noticed that my list items are not ordered anymore? Why is this?

Comment: It's because of this:


#list li
{
    display: inline;
}

The <li> tags are set to display as inline, and when they are inline the ordering won't show but instead they will be displayed all on the same line. 

If you want the ordering to show, just remove all the code above in the comment and it should show that as a list with numbering 1. 2. 3... etc.

Answer (score 2):

You have to reset default list padding added by browsers:

```
#list
{
    padding-left:0;
}
```

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/nvuqf7wL/1/

You should choose on of 2 centring methods:
-margin:auto;
-text-align: center;

First one (margin auto) is better if you can know width of container/list and you don't want centre content of this container. in this particular example this will centre ul but li not.

Second method(text-align) is used if you don't know width of container but if you don't want to centre content of this container you have to reset it to left on child/children.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/nvuqf7wL/3/

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'link' your html file with your css file. The way to do this is to add this line into your html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourcssfilename.css">
```

Just add it so your whole html file looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<div id = "listwrapper">
                <h3>Partner Companies</h3>
                <ol id = "list">
                    <li><a href="http://store.steampowered.com/app/241240/">Steam Contraption maker</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.gamingonlinux.com/articles/contraption-maker-casual-game-will-come-to-linux.3026">Contraptions coming to Linux</a></li>
                    <li><a href="unity3d.com/">Unity game developer engine</a></li>
                </ol>
            </div>
```

I tried your code by just adding that line and it works as shown:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

If you want it to show like this:

[image]

Then in your css file, remove this:

```
#list li
{
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: you dont "Need" to Link the css file... havent you heard of "Style" tags?

Comment: That is the other way to do it yes. Just use the style tag and it will work. This gentleman has a css file already.